# CanvaJs: The 10 first (sorted) Elements in the given array

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

So this is my issue.

I have a chart with bars (a top chart) and I have a huge list of elements which is unsorted. My goal is to give the list of elements to the chart that is gonna sort it and give me the first 10 elements only (sorted).

And this is a code summary:

```
Array = [[User 1, 25],[User 2, 45],[User 3, 11],etc...]
```

I've tried to setup a maximum on the `Axis X` like this:

```
 var chart_top_user = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer_top_user", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            axisX:{
                maximum: 10,
                interval: 1
            },
```

But it only shows the first 10 elements given (unsorted). Can someone tell me if this is possible with `Canvajs`, or do I have to sort and limit the list myself?

Sorry for my bad English. I tried to be as complete as possible.

Thank you all for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

CanvasJS doesn't sort datapoints that you pass to it, it just renders in the sequence you pass. You can sort it and get just top 10 users before passing to chart-options. Checkout an example below.

```js
var dps = [
  { label: "User 1", y: 610 },
  { label: "User 2", y: 680 },
  { label: "User 3", y: 690 },
  { label: "User 4", y: 700 },
  { label: "User 5", y: 710 },
  { label: "User 6", y: 658 },
  { label: "User 7", y: 734 },
  { label: "User 8", y: 963 },
  { label: "User 9", y: 847 },
  { label: "User 10",  y: 853 },
  { label: "User 11",  y: 869 },
  { label: "User 12",  y: 943 },
  { label: "User 13",  y: 970 },
  { label: "User 14",  y: 869 },
  { label: "User 15",  y: 890 },
  { label: "User 16",  y: 930 },
  { label: "User 17",  y: 850 },
  { label: "User 18",  y: 905 },
  { label: "User 19",  y: 980 },
  { label: "User 20",  y: 858 },
  { label: "User 21",  y: 734 },
  { label: "User 22",  y: 963 },
  { label: "User 23",  y: 847 },
  { label: "User 24",  y: 853 },
  { label: "User 25",  y: 869 },
  { label: "User 26",  y: 943 },
  { label: "User 27",  y: 970 },
  { label: "User 28",  y: 869 },
  { label: "User 29",  y: 890 },
  { label: "User 30",  y: 930 },
  { label: "User 31",  y: 750 }
];

var top10Dps = getHighestValues(dps, 10);
//var top10Dps = dps;

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  title:{
    text: "Website Traffic"
  },
  axisY: {
    //includeZero: true
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: top10Dps
  }]
});
chart.render();

function getHighestValues(dps, num){
  var topDps = [...dps].sort((a, b) => b.y - a.y).slice(0, num);
  return topDps;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 180px; width: 100%;"></div>
```